# sum 2 fields in a collection and put the results into the third field

Tags: powerapps

I have a collection (ColGridData) with 40 columns, and I'm trying to sum the 2 columns and put the results into 3rd.  The first field is a dropdown, the second field is a numeric field, and the results goes into the third.  The user could manually enter the data into either Boost or 'Final Weight'.

Ideal scenario is when the user changes either the 'Weight' or 'Boost' the 'Final Weight' would be updated to 7.

[image: Snapshot of the 3 fields]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give an example code and setup in Power Apps to achieve your requirements. You can refer this to make adjustments in your app.

Considering, you have data/columns like below in your `ColGridData`:

```
ClearCollect(
    ColGridData,
    {
        Weight: 3,
        Boost: 4,
        FinalWeight: ""
    },
    {
        Weight: 4,
        Boost: 5,
        FinalWeight: ""
    }
)
```

Used above collection as `items` property of the gallery control - which contains 3 more controls inside it: 1 drop down and 2 text inputs:

[image]

**Dropdown control setup (Weight)**:

`Items` property:

```
Table({Value: 1},{Value: 2},{Value: 3},{Value: 4},{Value: 5})
```

`Default` property:

```
ThisItem.Weight
```

**First text input control (Boost)**:

`Default` property:

```
ThisItem.Boost
```

**Second text input control (Final Weight)**:

`Default` property:

```
ThisItem.FinalWeight
```

---

Now, use below formulas to update the `FinalWeight` column in collection when you change the Boost or Weight field values:

Set `OnChange` property of drop down control (Weight) and first text input control (Boost) to:

```
Patch(
    ColGridData,
    ThisItem,
    {FinalWeight: Value(ddWeight.Selected.Value) + Value(txtBoost.Text)}
)
```

**Output**:

[image]